# Looping an XML file with VBA

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro to get info from an XML and parsing using MSXML2. As you can see from the XML below some of the child nodes have the same row number and I am trying to see what the best way is for me to go through the child nodes with the same row number and output that info to the same row line of the spreadsheet. For example I want everything that has row 2 to be on line 13 of the excel, then row 3 will be on line 14 since "i" will increase to 1..

```
Sub ModifierItems()
    Set itemchecknode = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/ExportData/LineItemList/LineItem/RowType/text()")
    Set itemnumnode = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/ExportData/LineItemList/LineItem/Product/text()")
    Set itemdescnode = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/ExportData/LineItemList/LineItem/Description/text()")
    Set itemlistnode = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/ExportData/LineItemList/LineItem/cpListPrice/text()")
    Set itemcountnode = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/ExportData/LineItemList/LineItem")
    Set itemreslnode = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/ExportData/LineItemList/LineItem/cpUnitPrice/text()")
    Set itemrownumnode = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/ExportData/LineItemList/LineItem/RowNum/text()")

    For i = 0 To (itemcountnode.Length - 1)
        itemnum = itemnumnode(i).NodeValue
        itemdesc = itemdescnode(i).NodeValue
        itemlist = itemlistnode(i).NodeValue
        itemrownum = itemrownumnode(i).NodeValue
        itembdnum = itembdnumnode(i).NodeValue
        itemresl = itemreslnode(i).NodeValue
        xmlWK.Range("A" & i + 13).Value = itemnum
        xmlWK.Range("B" & i + 13).Value = itemdesc
        xmlWK.Range("C" & i + 13).Value = itemlist
        xmlWK.Range("D" & i + 13).Value = itemresl
    Next    
End Sub
```

[CLICK HERE FOR THE Sample XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Hkt.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExportData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <CustomerNumber>100</CustomerNumber>
    <City>Plain</City>
    <ZipCode>41803</ZipCode>
  </Header>
  <LineItemList>
    <LineItem>
      <Product>719-AF21</Product>
      <RowNum>2</RowNum>
      <RowType>Product</RowType>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <Description>H380Gen</Description>
      <cpListPrice>1000</cpListPrice>
      <cpUnitPrice>100</cpUnitPrice>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
      <Product>72</Product>
      <RowNum>2</RowNum>
      <RowType>Discount</RowType>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <Description xsi:nil="true"/>
      <cpListPrice>0</cpListPrice>
      <cpUnitPrice>0</cpUnitPrice>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
      <Product>06</Product>
      <RowNum>2</RowNum>
      <RowType>Discount</RowType>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <Description xsi:nil="true"/>
      <cpListPrice>0</cpListPrice>
      <cpUnitPrice>0</cpUnitPrice>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
      <Product>A9</Product>
      <RowNum>2</RowNum>
      <RowType>Discount</RowType>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <Description xsi:nil="true"/>
      <cpListPrice>0</cpListPrice>
      <cpUnitPrice>0</cpUnitPrice>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
      <Product>7190-zb21</Product>
      <RowNum>3</RowNum>
      <RowType>ProductOption</RowType>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <Description>U.S.</Description>
      <cpListPrice>0</cpListPrice>
      <cpUnitPrice>0</cpUnitPrice>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
      <Product>06</Product>
      <RowNum>3</RowNum>   
      <RowType>Discount</RowType> 
      <Qty>1</Qty>    
      <Description xsi:nil="true"/>    
      <cpListPrice>0</cpListPrice>    
      <cpUnitPrice>0</cpUnitPrice>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
      <Product>A9</Product>    
      <RowNum>3</RowNum>    
      <RowType>Discount</RowType>    
      <Qty>1</Qty>    
      <Description xsi:nil="true"/>    
      <cpListPrice>0</cpListPrice>    
      <cpUnitPrice>0</cpUnitPrice>
    </LineItem>
  </LineItemList>
</ExportData>
```

Click here for the output
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uwSh.jpg)

Comment: It would be easier if you'd paste an XML here or link to service like http://pastie.org/

Comment: @malarzm I posted the XML as a picture. The reason is because I tried pasting the XML but it was not pasting right. It would end up in a bad format. Click on the link where it says sample XML.

Comment: It would be safer to iterate over `itemcountnode` and select the child nodes of each element node directly.  Unfortunately since your XML is a picture that's difficult for anyone to test...  You should be able to include it if you format it using the code button.

Comment: @TimWilliams I really tried pasting the XML info but for whatever reason it is spitting out the above. Let me know if you want me to send you a notedpad with the info.

Comment: Code (or XML) as a picture is useless. It can't be copied and pasted for testing or debugging. Images should be used only to demonstrate things you can't explain any other way, not as an escape from taking the time to learn to properly format your content. (There are nearly a dozen more reasons to avoid images in your posts, which you can see in [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576).)

Comment: I've fixed your formatting. The XML you included in your post was a) excessively long and repetitive, and b) non-parseable (XML can contain only a single root node, and what you posted has two). For future reference, when posting code (or XML) here, get it properly indented and arranged in your favorite editor, then copy and paste it here, select the entire block you just pasted, and either press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button on the toolbar. For single lines or embedded code, surround it with backticks (`Sub MyProc()`). For formatting help, click the `?` above the top right corner.

Comment: @kenwhite I appreciate your help fixing the XML.

Comment: @TimWilliams. I updated the XML hopefully you can help.

Comment: @TimWilliams I posted an output that I expect from the XML. Let me know if you can assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This tested OK for me:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
    Dim objNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList, o As Object
    Dim rowtype, itemnum, itemdesc, itemlist, itemresl, rownum
    Dim sht As Worksheet, f As Range, sep

    xmlDoc.async = False

    'xmlDoc.Load "D:\Analysis\config.xml"
    xmlDoc.LoadXML Range("A1").Value
    xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

    If xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then

        MsgBox "Error!" & vbCrLf & _
        "  Line: " & xmlDoc.parseError.Line & vbCrLf & _
        "  Text:" & xmlDoc.parseError.srcText & vbCrLf & _
        "  Reason: " & xmlDoc.parseError.reason

    Else

        Set objNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ExportData/LineItemList/LineItem")
        If objNodes.Length = 0 Then
          Debug.Print "not found"
        Else

            Set sht = ActiveSheet

            For Each o In objNodes

                rownum = GetNodeVal(o, "RowNum/text()")
                rowtype = GetNodeVal(o, "RowType/text()")
                itemnum = GetNodeVal(o, "Product/text()")
                itemdesc = GetNodeVal(o, "Description/text()")
                itemlist = GetNodeVal(o, "cpListPrice/text()")
                itemresl = GetNodeVal(o, "cpUnitPrice/text()")

                If Len(rownum) = 0 Then rownum = 999

                'is this rownum already listed?
                Set f = sht.Range("A13:A10000").Find(rownum, , xlValues, xlWhole)
                If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    sep = vbLf 'already listed: set newline
                Else
                    'not listed: add it
                    Set f = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    f.Value = rownum
                    sep = "" 'no newline separator needed
                End If

                'add the values....
                With f.EntireRow
                    .Cells(2).Value = .Cells(2).Value & sep & itemdesc
                    .Cells(3).Value = .Cells(3).Value & sep & itemlist
                    .Cells(4).Value = .Cells(4).Value & sep & itemresl
                    .Cells(5).Value = .Cells(5).Value & sep & rowtype
                End With

            Next o

        End If 'have line items

    End If 'parsed OK
End Sub

'get the value of a child node (which may or may not exist)
Function GetNodeVal(o As Object, xPath As String)
    Dim rv, el
    If Not o Is Nothing Then
        Set el = o.SelectSingleNode(xPath)
        If Not el Is Nothing Then rv = el.NodeValue
    End If
    GetNodeVal = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Tim thanks so much for your efforts on this, I really appreciate it, but my issue is that some of the nodes need to be on the same line in excel. I attached a pic of what the expected output based on the XML I gave. See above on my post for the pic I attached. Thanks.

Comment: please see output I posted that I expect from the XML I attached and let me know if you can assist. Thanks.